# How to select only the number from “show global status like 'Com_insert';”

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql and How can I select only the number result from "show global status like 'Comm_insert'"?

Comment: Please don't cross-post questions. http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/33915/1021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_STATUS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/status-table.html) table:

```
SELECT VARIABLE_VALUE
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_STATUS
WHERE  VARIABLE_NAME LIKE 'Com_insert'
```